# How to fire innergridview events

Tags: asp.net

I have one main gridview and child gridview.It showing all questions. for every question i have another gridview to show answer options.If i want to delete one answer option how can i delete????

Any answers or clues are appriciated

Comment: This was not at all clear please update your question with more input

Comment: i think now you can understood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In nested grid view we always handle events on the basis of row command event handler.And all link buttons are handled with row command.Apply conditions and use desired options according to you need

check this

http://www.vbdotnetheaven.com/UploadFile/nikhil_be_it/GridViewInsideGridView05232006004636AM/GridViewInsideGridView.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/EditNestedGridView.aspx?msg=2241690